# Prevent all outgoing requests from NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, security

Is there any existing technique or npm package that can prevent all outgoing requests from a NodeJS server, allowing only responses to incoming requests?  This could prevent phone-home type attacks in deep dependencies missed in security audits.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like your application would be something to prevent something or somebody from installing something on your server.

Comment: @dollarVar node.js and npm have a dependency resolution which can get quite deep (transitive dependencies). Nobody will install an application, but sometimes it's not easy to overlook all effective dependencies. A desaster if one of the dependencies contains malware.

Comment: Ok, if you think something that **you** installed is phoning home, monitor the outgoing traffic and find the culprit, throw him out, and never trust a package of that developer again. If you could not find the culprit, gobble up the code of the `http.request()`, so that it does not connect anymore, but dependencies on that (trying to phone home) do not kill the server due to an error. I am shocked, let me throw something in to get the nerves down http://nodejsreactions.tumblr.com/post/64305120115/frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

A firewall.

That's truly the only way.  Remember though that there is nothing stopping some code from accepting commands from clients connecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/block-outgoing-network-access-for-a-single-user-from-my-server-using-iptables.html
- https://superuser.com/questions/95963/lightweight-solution-to-block-outbound-connections-from-a-specific-app

The first link shows a firewall rule bound to a particular user. Easy and simple. Why use another npm module with deep dependencies you don't want to trust ;-)

Comment: Sorry, where I´m at? How can a user initiate a network request of the server? And btw, in your first link he is confusedly writing about "hackers downloading code into your server using wget"...ehhm?

Comment: @dollarVar server processes most often run under a particular user, e.g. some webservers as `www-data`. It's not a human user, but a technical user. Now clear what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for pure node.js solution, you can do something like that.

Using some module like `mockery` you can limit what calls your javascript module can do to node.js core. For example, if you override `require('net').connect`, it'll make harder for malicious code to execute something.

I don't know of any existing solutions, but it's definitely possible, and I'd really like to see one.

---

That said, the generic approaches to this problem are completely outside of node.js scope:

1. firewall
2. apparmor