# How to sandbox a node app to prevent unwanted outgoing traffic

Tags: node.js

npm and all the other public buckets of opensource code... they all have the ability to inject code into an app that could simply ping a remote endpoint and do something dodgy.

it is not possible to stop the tide and get everyone in my team to stop using npm/packagist/pip etc etc.. but in nodejs, is there a way to block potential threats over http?

By this i mean, before initializing my app, call some whitelist service that would then double check each http request to ensure it was on a whitelist.

There is an army of tools to help incoming requests.. but how the hell can i secure from an inside attack? One day a junior is going to install some npm dep that has some dodgy crypo miner, or logger buried inside it.

Comment: This is a process problem, not a technical one. "One day a junior is going to install some npm dep that has some dodgy crypo miner, or logger buried inside it"—this is what code review is for. (And a bunch of other process stuff, including open communication, a shared strategy around adding and managing dependencies, etc. All developers and reviewers should do at least some basic due diligence around libraries they use. Depending on your use case, you could do more. I know that some organizations do a full audit of all libraries.)

Comment: There are some ideas here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026824>

Comment: @Chris to apply a full audit on ALL libraries is usually too time consuming on npm unless you budgets are giant..

Comment: @John, that's why I said _some_ organizations. Generally, I find a bit of review enough. The point was that this is a workflow problem and you need a workflow solution.

Comment: MRs are good - but with todays typescript express app there are so many dependencies it is impractical to review the code of the dependencies. When the client needs something like AWS or any other major provider the input output firewalls are put in place... but there is still the time when the client doesn't want to pay for all this.. maybe a proof of concept app on a super tight budget.. in this world a simple whitelist of permitted outgoing http requests is phenomenally cheaper. I hear you and agree to a point..